# Not reading Input file to run stress autocorrelation function

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am trying to run a stress autocorrelation function code to calculate the stress autocorrelation function,then from there I would like to calculate viscosity using Green -Kubo equation. Now the Fortran code I have does not read out my stress data in order to calculate stress auot-correlarion function. Anyone can please help me with this. I have attached my code and data I want to correlate. Hope to here from you soon.

Here is the error

```
./a.out
**** Program Stress_autocorrelation ****
Calculation of time Correlation Functions
Enter data file name
DFILE
Enter results file name
RFILE
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
At line 106 of file main.f95 (unit = 10, file = 'DFILE')
Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read
```

Code and below is Input data:

```
  ! Program to claculate pressure autocorrelation function

    program stress_autocorrelation
      implicit none

    common / block1 / STORA, STORB, STORC, STORD,STORE,STORF,STORG, STORH, STORI
    common / block2 / PA, PB, PC, PD, PE, PF, PG, PH , PI
    common / block3 / PACF, ANORM

    ! *******************************************************************
    ! ............  PRINCIPAL VARIABLES............
    !
    ! ** integer  N               Number of atoms
    ! ** integer  NSTEP           Number of  steps on the tape
    ! ** integer  IOR             Interval for time origins
    ! ** integer  NT              Correlation length, Including T=0
    ! ** integer  NTIMOR          Number of time origin
    ! ** integer  NLABEL          Label for step (1,2,3.....Nstep)
    !
    !
    ! ** real PACF(NT)            The pressure correlation function
    ! ** NSTEP and NT should be multiples of IOR.
    ! ** PA,PB,PC = Pxx,Pxy,Pxz
    ! ** PD,PE,PF = Pyx,Pyy,Pyz
    ! ** PG,PH,PI = Pzx,Pzy,Pzz
    !
    !
    ! ...............ROUTINES REFERENCED..........................
    !
    ! ....Subroutine Store (J1)..........
    !Routine to store the data for correlation
    ! .....Subroutine Corr (J1,J2,IT).........
    !Routine to correlate the stored time origin
    !
    !
    ! .....................USAGE..............................
    !
    ! Data in file DFILE on fortrran UNIT DUNIT
    ! Results in File RFILE on fortran UNIT RUNIT
    ! *******************************************************************

    integer N, NSTEP, IOR, NT, NDIM, DUNIT, RUNIT, NTIMOR
    integer FULLUP
    parameter ( N = 78, NSTEP = 10, IOR = 4, NT = 8 )
    parameter ( DUNIT = 10, RUNIT = 11 )
    parameter ( NDIM = NT / IOR + 1, NTIMOR = NSTEP / IOR )
    parameter ( FULLUP = NDIM - 1 )


    real PA(N), PB(N), PC(N), PD(N), PE(N), PF(N), PG(N), PH(N), PI(N)
    real STORA(NDIM,N), STORB(NDIM,N), STORC(NDIM,N),STORD(NDIM,N), STORE(NDIM,N),STORF(NDIM,N),STORG(NDIM,N),STORH(NDIM,N)
    real STORI(NDIM,N)
    REAL PACF(NT), ANORM(NT)

    integer S(NTIMOR), TM(NTIMOR)
    integer TS, TSS, L, NINCOR, K, R, JA, IB, IN, IA, JO, I
    integer NLABEL

    character DUMMY * 5
    character DFILE * 115
    character RFILE * 115

    ! *******************************************************************

    write(*,'('' **** Program Stress_autocorrelation **** '')')
    write(*,'('' Calculation of time Correlation Functions '')')

    !.....READ IN FILE NAMES.........

    write(*,'('' Enter data file name'')')
    read (*,'(A)') DFILE
    write (*,'('' Enter results file name'')')
    read (*,'(A)') RFILE

    !......INITIALIZE COUNTERS.......

    NINCOR = FULLUP
    JA = 1
    IA = 1
    IB = 1

    !........ZERO ARRAYS.............

    do 5 I = 1, NT
    PACF(I) = 0.0
    ANORM(I) = 0.0
    write(*,*) PACF(I)
    5 continue


    !..........OPEN DATA FILE AND RESULTS FILE...........

    open ( UNIT = DUNIT, FILE = DFILE, STATUS = 'OLD', FORM = 'FORMATTED')

    open ( UNIT = RUNIT, FILE = RFILE, STATUS = 'NEW' )

    !.........CALCULATION BEGINS............

    do 40 L = 1, NTIMOR

    JA = JA + 1
    S(L) = JA - 1

    read ( DUNIT, '(A5,I4)') DUMMY, NLABEL
    do 7 R = 1, N
    read (DUNIT,'(F9.6,8(9X,F9.6))')PA(R),PB(R),PC(R),PD(R),PE(R),PF(R),PG(R),PH(R),PI(R)
    7 continue

    TM(L) = NLABEL
    write(*,*) TM(L)

    !.......STORE STEP AS A TIME ORIGIN......

    call STOREE ( JA )

    !........CORRELATE THE ORIGINS IN STORE......

    do 10 IN = IA, L

    TSS = TM(L) - TM(IN)
    TS = TSS + 1
    JO = S(IN) + 1
    call CORR ( JO, JA, TS )

    10 continue

    !Read IN data between time origins. This can
    !Be conveniently stored IN element 1 of the
    !Array storx etc. and can then ben correlated
    !With the time origins

    do 30 K = 1, IOR - 1

    read ( DUNIT, '(A5,I4)') DUMMY, NLABEL
    do 15 R = 1, N
    read ( DUNIT,'(F17.14,8(13X,F17.14))')PA(R),PB(R),PC(R),PD(R),PE(R),PF(R),PG(R),PH(R),PI(R)
    15 continue

    call STOREE ( 1 )

    do 20 IN = IA, L

    TSS = NLABEL - TM(IN)
    TS = TSS + 1
    JO = S(IN) + 1
    call CORR ( JO, 1, TS )

    20 continue

    30 continue

    if ( L .GE. FULLUP ) then
    if ( L .EQ. NINCOR ) then
    NINCOR = NINCOR + FULLUP
    JA = 1
    endif

    IA = IA + 1

    endif

    40 continue

    close ( DUNIT )

    !.....NORMALISE CORRELATION FUNCTIONS.......

    PACF(1) = PACF(1) / ANORM(1) / REAL ( N )

    do 50 I = 2, NT

    PACF(I) = PACF(I) / ANORM(I) / REAL ( N ) / PACF(1)

    50 continue

    write ( RUNIT, '('' Pressure ACF '')')
    write ( RUNIT, '(I6,E15.6)') ( I, PACF(I), I = 1, NT )

    close ( RUNIT )

    stop
    end



    subroutine STOREE ( J1 )
    common / BLOCK1 / STORA, STORB, STORC, STORD,STORE,STORF,STORG,STORH,STORI
    common/ BLOCK2 / PA, PB, PC, PD, PE, PF, PG, PH, PI


    ! *******************************************************************
    !.........SUBROUTINE TO STORE TIME ORIGINS..............
    ! *******************************************************************


    integer J1
    integer N, NT, IOR, NDIM
    parameter ( N = 78, NT = 8, IOR =4 )
    parameter ( NDIM = NT / IOR + 1 )

    real STORA(NDIM,N), STORB(NDIM,N), STORC(NDIM,N),STORD(NDIM,N)
    real STORE(NDIM,N),STORF(NDIM,N),STORG(NDIM,N),STORH(NDIM,N),STORI(NDIM,N)
    real PA(N), PB(N), PC(N), PD(N), PE(N), PF(N),PG(N), PH(N), PI(N)
    integer I


    do 10 I = 1, N

    STORA(J1,I) = PA(I)
    STORB(J1,I) = PB(I)
    STORC(J1,I) = PC(I)
    STORD(J1,I) = PD(I)
    STORE(J1,I) = PE(I)
    STORF(J1,I) = PF(I)
    STORG(J1,I) = PG(I)
    STORH(J1,I) = PH(I)
    STORI(J1,I) = PI(I)
    10 continue

    return
    end


    subroutine CORR ( J1, J2, IT )
    common / block1 / STORA, STORB, STORC, STORD,STORE,STORF,STORG,STORH,STORI
    common/ block3 / PACF, ANORM

    ! *******************************************************************
    !......SUBROUTINE TO CORRELATE TIME ORIGINS....
    ! *******************************************************************

    integer J1, J2, IT
    integer N, NT, IOR, NDIM
    parameter ( N = 78, NT = 8, IOR = 4 )
    parameter ( NDIM = NT / IOR + 1 )

    real STORA(NDIM,N), STORB(NDIM,N), STORC(NDIM,N),STORD(NDIM,N)
    real STORE(NDIM,N),STORF(NDIM,N),STORG(NDIM,N),STORH(NDIM,N),STORI(NDIM,N)

    real PACF(NT), ANORM(NT)
    integer I

    !********************************************************************

    do 10 I = 1, N

    PACF(IT) = PACF(IT) + STORA(J1,I) * STORA(J2,I) &
                        + STORB(J1,I) * STORB(J2,I) &
                        + STORC(J1,I) * STORC(J2,I) &
                        + STORD(J1,I) * STORD(J2,I) &
                        + STORE(J1,I) * STORE(J2,I) &
                        + STORF(J1,I) * STORF(J2,I) &
                        + STORG(J1,I) * STORG(J2,I) &
                        + STORH(J1,I) * STORH(J2,I) &
                        + STORI(J1,I) * STORI(J2,I)
    10 continue

    ANORM(IT) = ANORM(IT) + 1.0

    return
    end
```

Data: has 9 columns

```
        -9.568336E+00 -1.615161E+00 1.042644E+00 -1.615161E+00 -1.131916E+01 -6.979813E-01 1.042644E+00 -6.979813E-01 -1.182917E+01
        -4.765572E-01 9.005122E-01 -2.282920E+00 9.005122E-01 -3.827857E+00 -3.206736E+00 -2.282920E+00 -3.206736E+00 -6.252462E+00
        -1.012710E+01 4.672368E-01 8.791873E-02 4.672368E-01 -4.680832E+00 -5.271814E-01 8.791873E-02 -5.271814E-01 -1.898345E-01
        -7.699012E+00 -9.906154E-01 7.450304E-01 -9.906154E-01 -1.061230E+00 -3.546956E+00 7.450304E-01 -3.546956E+00 -6.843898E+00
        -3.544260E+00 4.254020E+00 -1.963602E+00 4.254020E+00 3.740858E+00 -4.587760E+00 -1.963602E+00 -4.587760E+00 -6.776258E+00
        1.755595E-01 -9.625855E-01 -2.395960E+00 -9.625855E-01 -1.701399E+00 -8.483695E-01 -2.395960E+00 -8.483695E-01 -4.165223E+00
        -3.244186E+00 5.540608E+00 -4.951768E-01 5.540608E+00 3.068601E+00 -1.613010E-01 -4.951768E-01 -1.613010E-01 -5.641277E+00
        -8.985849E+00 1.870244E+00 -2.295795E-01 1.870244E+00 -4.635924E+00 -4.787461E+00 -2.295795E-01 -4.787461E+00 -3.014272E+00
        -1.651073E-01 -6.326584E-01 -3.028051E+00 -6.326584E-01 -2.621833E+00 -2.640439E+00 -3.028051E+00 -2.640439E+00 1.668877E+00
        1.250349E+00 3.054784E+00 -2.898975E+00 3.054784E+00 8.419503E-01 9.620184E-01 -2.898975E+00 9.620184E-01 1.479256E+00
        -7.796195E-01 1.942983E+00 -2.736569E+00 1.942983E+00 6.073043E+00 -2.520281E+00 -2.736569E+00 -2.520281E+00 -9.600832E-01
        4.697066E-01 3.138124E+00 -1.092573E+00 3.138124E+00 -2.099285E+00 -1.581031E+00 -1.092573E+00 -1.581031E+00 -6.285002E-01
        3.017532E-01 -9.701574E-02 1.611936E+00 -9.701574E-02 -1.762075E+00 -3.401961E+00 1.611936E+00 -3.401961E+00 -6.889746E-01
        1.177410E-01 5.090611E-01 1.452691E-01 5.090611E-01 5.695570E+00 -3.573245E+00 1.452691E-01 -3.573245E+00 -1.099615E+00
        -5.180126E+00 -1.876409E-01 -2.067182E+00 -1.876409E-01 1.611177E+00 5.458450E-01 -2.067182E+00 5.458450E-01 1.026071E+00
        1.477567E+00 1.598949E+00 -1.577546E+00 1.598949E+00 3.933810E+00 -2.698132E+00 -1.577546E+00 -2.698132E+00 3.485029E+00
        -2.533324E+00 1.753033E+00 1.425241E-01 1.753033E+00 2.406501E+00 -1.147217E+00 1.425241E-01 -1.147217E+00 3.065603E-01
        -2.360274E+00 1.312721E+00 -3.711419E-01 1.312721E+00 2.556935E+00 3.152605E-01 -3.711419E-01 3.152605E-01 3.378170E+00
        -1.698217E+00 1.105760E+00 3.780822E-01 1.105760E+00 2.736574E+00 7.920578E-01 3.780822E-01 7.920578E-01 -6.596856E-01
        -5.099544E+00 1.647542E-01 -1.036544E+00 1.647542E-01 3.845429E+00 -1.034068E+00 -1.036544E+00 -1.034068E+00 -3.152053E+00
        -2.686567E+00 1.335786E+00 -1.889911E-01 1.335786E+00 9.755267E-01 9.322043E-01 -1.889911E-01 9.322043E-01 3.229615E-01
        1.542994E-01 3.104663E+00 -1.634353E-01 3.104663E+00 4.090105E+00 -1.128244E+00 -1.634353E-01 -1.128244E+00 -2.909383E-01
        -4.235419E-01 1.554157E+00 3.475430E+00 1.554157E+00 4.701173E+00 -1.789414E+00 3.475430E+00 -1.789414E+00 1.517218E+00
        -8.054924E-01 -1.167935E+00 -1.123460E+00 -1.167935E+00 1.169303E+00 -2.171076E+00 -1.123460E+00 -2.171076E+00 -5.636150E+00
```

Comment: What is the actual error? What did you try to solve it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information. Since the results file name is read from STDIN, please also include what you specify when the program is run.

Comment: **Please edit your question**.

Comment: @somu at the bottom of your question, just below the tags and above these comments are a few links, one of them says *edit*.  Click on the word edit and you will be able to edit your post.

Comment: the error seems clear enough, you are trying to open a file that elready exists with `status=new`

Comment: You *must* edit your question to include all extra information.
Do *not* add this extra info in comments.

Comment: well now after your edit its an entirely different error. *if* the stuff you show after "Data: has 9 columns" is the entirety of the file the the error is because "your" code is expecting a header line with an integer.  It seems clear to me you didn't write this code and know little or nothing about fortran.  There are plenty of tutorials out there to get you started.